# How Can I convert this SQL Command to Django ORM code

Tags: python, django

I have just started using Django. I wanted to get data with the following sqlquery

```
select StudentDetails.First_Name,StudentDetails.Last_Name,StudentDetails.LecClass,StudentDetails.Student_Id, AttendenceDetails.Time from StudentDetails,AttendenceDetails where StudentDetails.Mac_Address = AttendenceDetails.Mac_Address and AttendenceDetails.LecClass = "273" and AttendenceDetails.Date = curdate()
```

My Models are

```
class Attendencedetails(models.Model):
slno = models.AutoField(db_column='SlNo', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
mac_address = models.CharField(db_column='Mac_Address', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
lecclass = models.CharField(db_column='LecClass', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
date = models.DateField(db_column='Date')  # Field name made lowercase.
time = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Time')  # Field name made lowercase.
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'AttendenceDetails'
    unique_together = (('mac_address', 'lecclass', 'date'),)
```

Second Table:

```
class Studentdetails(models.Model):
slno = models.AutoField(db_column='SlNo', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
first_name = models.CharField(db_column='First_Name', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
last_name = models.CharField(db_column='Last_Name', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
student_id = models.CharField(db_column='Student_Id', max_length=9)  # Field name made lowercase.
mac_address = models.CharField(db_column='Mac_Address', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
lecclass = models.CharField(db_column='LecClass', max_length=5)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'StudentDetails'
    unique_together = (('student_id', 'mac_address', 'lecclass'),)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The most important point is that you don't need to. If you have the query just use it

Comment: I dont think, you can.
There is foreignkey releationship and django manages this with a column field_id,  I dont think you can overcome this. I saw you join with mac_address.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
StudentDetails.objects.filter(Mac_Address=AttendenceDetails.object.get(LecClass='273', Date=today()).Mac_Address).values_list('First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'LecClass', 'Student_Id', flat=True)
```

Although, a better solution is it to have a foreign key to establish a direct relationship between these two models